# RAID1 unmounted during boot as degraded but can be mounted fine manually

Tags: fedora, boot, raid1

I'm running Fedora Server Edition 26 and I have two external USB drives with a partition on each that I have combined in RAID1. My /etc/fstab file has this line for automounting the array:

```
UUID=B0C4-A677 /mnt/backup-raid exfat uid=strwrsdbz,gid=strwrsdbz,umask=022,windows_names,locale=en.utf8,nobootwait,nofail 0 2
```

However, when booting is finished the array at /mnt/backup-raid is not mounted. If I check the journal logs I see

```
Oct 28 21:32:07 hostname systemd[1]: Started File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/B0C4-A677.
Oct 28 21:32:07 hostname audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-B0C4\x2dA677 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Oct 28 21:32:07 hostname kernel: audit: type=1130 audit(1509240727.851:75): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-B0C4\x2dA677 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Oct 28 21:32:08 hostname systemd[1]: Mounting /mnt/backup-raid...
Oct 28 21:32:08 hostname systemd[1]: Mounted /mnt/c.
Oct 28 21:32:08 hostname ntfs-3g[702]: Version 2017.3.23 integrated FUSE 28
Oct 28 21:32:08 hostname ntfs-3g[702]: Mounted /dev/sda1 (Read-Write, label "", NTFS 3.1)
Oct 28 21:32:08 hostname ntfs-3g[702]: Cmdline options: rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=022,windows_names,locale=en.utf8
Oct 28 21:32:08 hostname ntfs-3g[702]: Mount options: rw,allow_other,nonempty,relatime,default_permissions,fsname=/dev/sda1,blkdev,blksize=4096
Oct 28 21:32:08 hostname ntfs-3g[702]: Global ownership and permissions enforced, configuration type 7
Oct 28 21:32:08 hostname lvm[599]:   3 logical volume(s) in volume group "fedora" now active
Oct 28 21:32:08 hostname systemd[1]: Started LVM2 PV scan on device 8:5.
Oct 28 21:32:08 hostname audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=lvm2-pvscan@8:5 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Oct 28 21:32:08 hostname kernel: audit: type=1130 audit(1509240728.594:76): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=lvm2-pvscan@8:5 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Oct 28 21:32:08 hostname systemd[1]: Found device /dev/mapper/fedora-home.
Oct 28 21:32:08 hostname systemd[1]: Mounting /home...
Oct 28 21:32:08 hostname kernel: XFS (dm-2): Mounting V4 Filesystem
Oct 28 21:32:08 hostname systemd[1]: Mounted /mnt/igel1.
Oct 28 21:32:08 hostname systemd-fsck[666]: /dev/sda3: clean, 376/128016 files, 291819/512000 blocks
Oct 28 21:32:08 hostname systemd[1]: Mounted /mnt/igel2.
Oct 28 21:32:08 hostname systemd[1]: Mounted /mnt/backup-raid.
```

*snip*

```
Oct 28 21:32:33 hostname systemd[1]: Created slice system-mdadm\x2dlast\x2dresort.slice.
Oct 28 21:32:33 hostname systemd[1]: Starting Activate md array even though degraded...
Oct 28 21:32:33 hostname systemd[1]: Unmounting /mnt/backup-raid...
Oct 28 21:32:34 hostname systemd[1]: Started Activate md array even though degraded.
Oct 28 21:32:34 hostname audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=mdadm-last-resort@md0 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Oct 28 21:32:34 hostname audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=mdadm-last-resort@md0 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Oct 28 21:32:34 hostname kernel:  md0:
Oct 28 21:32:34 hostname systemd[1]: Unmounted /mnt/backup-raid.
```

So it looks like it gets mounted in that first log block but then later it gets unmounted because it is appearing as degraded. But once it's finished booting I can run `sudo mount -a` and the array mounts without issue. The contents appear correctly in /mnt/backup-raid and checking /proc/mdstat shows

```
Personalities : [raid1]
md0 : active raid1 sdc2[0] sdb2[2]
      485345344 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/4 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

so everything looks healthy. In case it helps, my /etc/mdadm.conf contains

```
ARRAY /dev/md0 level=raid1 num-devices=2 metadata=1.2 name=hostname:backup-raid UUID=6c8bf3df:c4147eb1:4c3f88d8:e94d1dbc devices=/dev/sdb2,/dev/sdc2
```

I found [this email thread](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2017-January/038206.html) which appeared to be dealing with a similar situation but it looks to me like it just went silent. I'm sorry if the answer is in that email thread and I missed it but it just gets a bit too dense for me to follow.

Comment: another systemd bug?

Comment: It might be the drives are slow to spin up, or that the USB subsystem gets reinitialized in between the two RAID mount checks, making mdadm think the RAID got borked. Check for USB messages between the sections you pasted.

Comment: There are no messages with USB in them between the two journal blocks I included above. I gave the entries between the two blocks a skim by eye too and nothing obvious popped out as drives having problems or re-initializing.

Answer (score 3):

The 'Errorneous detection of degraded array' systemd-devel thread is about a race condition between udev and the mdadm-last-resort timer/service. The `Conflicts=sys-devices-virtual-block-%i.device` line then triggers the umount of the previously mounted filesystem.

The thread also [mentions a workaround](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2017-January/038223.html) that should also fix your issue: replace the `Conflicts=...` line with a `ConditionPathExissts=...` line:

```
# cp /usr/lib/systemd/system/mdadm-last-resort@.* /etc/systemd/system/
# sed -i 's@^Conflicts=sys-devices-virtual-block-%i.device@ConditionPathExists=/sys/devices/virtual/block/%i@' \
    /etc/systemd/system/mdadm-last-resort@.*
# shutdown -r now
```

Note that a drop-in replacement via `/etc/systemd/system/.../override.conf` [doesn't work for removing the `Conflicts=` line](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2017-June/038976.html).

You can subscribe to the related upstream systemd issue [Need a uni-directional version of "Conflicts"](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/5266) to get notified about changes regarding the underlying issue.

See also my [Fedora 27 bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1548729) where this issue manifests itself in `/boot/efi` not being mounted when placed on a RAID-1 mirror.

Comment: For the record, I've stopped using the computer since before this answer so I can't test the suggestions.

Comment: I just tested the suggestion and it worked great! Thank you Georg!